# Phantom Firewalls

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall

First, I should preface this with "I'm not entirely sure this is an Ubuntu question."  I work in a central office with many branches connected via VPN.  Some of the machines in the branches were failing to mount NFS shares from the central office, and I investigated.

What I found is that in every case of failure, running nmap against the NFS share host returned the same results:

All 1000 scanned ports on 10.x.x.x are filtered

There are no IPTables firewalls set up on any of the machines.  But it is as if a firewall sprung up on it's own.

The problem is often limited to one out of four machines at a branch.  The other machines report all the expected ports open on the NFS host via nmap.

The problem often resolves itself with no intervention.  It simply stops happening.

Resetting the VPN router will resolve the problem if the machines at the branch are directly connected to it, but not if they go through a switch.

Rebooting the machine will resolve the problem.  Running service network-manager restart doesn't resolve the problem.

The Ubuntu versions are largely 14.04 with some 12.04.

Answer (score -1):

Followup--this appears to be tied to instances running in vSphere.  Stand-alone machines aren't affected.  It doesn't look to be specifically an Ubuntu thing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer, but simply an update to the question. Please edit the question, rather than filling in answers. Also, as you've determined this isn't specific to Ubuntu, perhaps you could move the question to the [unix.se] site instead.